# Altering Java LookAndFeel via the command prompt

Tags: java, swing, look-and-feel

I have a Java program with a UI that uses LookAndFeel, I know that I can alter the program default theme via the command prompt using properties: java -Dswing.defaultlaf=Metal ....

In addition I know that I can alter the program font type using code :    UIManager.put("TextArea.font", new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 12));

My Question is whether it is possible to specifically switch fonts non programatically, either via a configuration file or a command prompt property, and if so could you give an exampe.

Thanks a bunch,
aag

Comment: Is the point "**Specifying the Look and Feel: swing.properties File**" in [How to Set the Look and Feel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html) what you are searching for?

Comment: I've seen it but couldn't manage to use it to specifically set a property, rather the entire theme.